# How to return the correct value from an int[] array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement

I'm new to Java (and programming in general), so apologies if some of this doesn't make sense and/or if the code is really bad:

I am trying get a unique four digit code from a user input (that is what the `Keyboard.readInput` line does), and I have put in a couple of conditional statements to ensure that the code that is entered can only be 4 digits and that each digit must be different to the other three.

The if statements work as intended in the sense that they output the error message and prompt them to re-enter (i.e. the method `getPlayerGuess()` gets called). For example, if the user enters 123 (i.e. `userGuess.length() != 4`), it will prompt them to enter again. If they then enter 1234, the method will complete.

However, the problem I have is that when I call this method in another class that I have, the code that is being pulled through is the first code entered (i.e. 123) and not the four digit one I want (i.e. 1234) - which is resulting in an array `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Any ideas on how I can ensure that the code that is being returned is the four digit one that passes the conditionals, and not the first one entered?

```
public int[] getPlayerGuess() {

    System.out.print("Guess a four digit code: ");
    String userGuess = Keyboard.readInput();

    if (userGuess.length() != 4) {
        System.out.print("Your code must be 4 digits - ");
        getPlayerGuess();
    }

    int[] userCode = createArrayFromGuess(userGuess);

    for (int i = 0; i < userCode.length-1; i++){
        for (int j = i+1; j < userCode.length; j++){
            if (userCode[i] == userCode[j]) {
                System.out.print("Code must have four unique digits - ");
                getPlayerGuess();
            }
        }
    }
    return userCode;
}
```

Comment: The problem with invoking `getPlayerGuess()` recursively is that you are just discarding the return value. And it doesn't really make sense to invoke recursively either: loop until the array is valid instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `getPlayerGuess()` which returns an `int[]` but you do not collect, nor assign the return value. Nor do you return it... so something like the following may work for you:

```
public int[] getPlayerGuess() {

  System.out.print("Guess a four digit code: ");
  String userGuess = Keyboard.readInput();

  if (userGuess.length() != 4) {
    System.out.print("Your code must be 4 digits - ");
    return getPlayerGuess(); // either assign or return the value that is actually calculated within that call...
  }

  int[] userCode = createArrayFromGuess(userGuess);

  for (int i = 0; i < userCode.length-1; i++){
      for (int j = i+1; j < userCode.length; j++){
          if (userCode[i] == userCode[j]) {
              System.out.print("Code must have four unique digits - ");
              return getPlayerGuess(); // either assign or return the value that is actually calculated within that call...
          }
      }
  }
  return userCode;
}
```

Simplifying your code a bit (not too much ;-)):

```
public int[] getPlayerGuess(String msg) {
    System.out.print(msg);
    String userGuess = Keyboard.readLine();
    if (userGuess.length() != 4) {
        return getPlayerGuess("\nYour code must be 4 digits - ");
    }
    if (userGuess.chars().distinct().count() != 4) {
        return getPlayerGuess("\nCode must have four unique digits - ");
    }
    return createArrayFromGuess(userGuess);
}
```

with the initial call being:

```
getPlayerGuess("Guess a four digit code: ");
```

Note that you can write this code also using an iterative approach. But I will leave that up to you.

Comment: Thanks very much - it makes sense now that I need to actually return the result of the new call for it to be used. And thanks for the tip on how to simplify the code a bit, looks a lot cleaner now.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
if (userGuess.length() != 4) {
      System.out.print("Your code must be 4 digits - ");
      getPlayerGuess();
    }
```

Yes, you call the method a second time, but you completely ignore that, and don't do anything with the result of it.

Change it to this:

```
if (userGuess.length() != 4) {
      System.out.print("Your code must be 4 digits - ");
      return getPlayerGuess();
    }
```

So you'll return the result of the new call, instead of completing the code after the if block.

EDIT:
A better approach would be:

```
System.out.print("Guess a four digit code: ");
String userGuess = Keyboard.readInput();

  while(userGuess.length() != 4) {
      System.out.print("Your code must be 4 digits - ");
      System.out.print("Guess a four digit code: ");
      userGuess = Keyboard.readInput();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much - it makes sense now that I need to actually return the result of the new call for it to be used.